# Listview is not refreshing when i delete the last remaining item flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, sqflite

I am trying to delete the last remaining item in a listview. When there is more than one item and i try to delete the one of them, the list is updating but not on last remaining item.

Here is my code!

// The following code is for displaying the listview.

```
_showTaskList() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Obx(
      () {
        return ListView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ),
          itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            Task task = _taskController.taskList[index];
            _taskController.getTask();
            if (task.repeat == 'Daily') {
              DateTime date =
                  DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime.toString());
              var myTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
              print(myTime);
              notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
                int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[0]),
                int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[1]),
                task,
              );
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Get.to(
                        () => NotifiedScreen(task: task),
                      ),
                      child: TaskTile(
                        task,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (task.date == DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate)) {
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _showBottomSheet(context, task);
                        // _taskController.getTask();
                      },
                      child: TaskTile(
                        task,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

this is delete bottomsheet.

```
_showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Task task) {
  Get.bottomSheet(
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
      height: task.isCompleted == 1
          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24
          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 6,
            width: 120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          task.isCompleted == 1
              ? Container()
              : _bottomSheetButton(
                  label: 'Task Completed',
                  onTap: () {
                    _taskController.markTaskCompleted(task.id!);
                    Get.back();
                  },
                  clr: Color(0xff2702DC),
                  context: context,
                ),
          _bottomSheetButton(
            label: 'Delete Task',
            onTap: () {
              _taskController.delete(task);
              
              Get.back();
             
            },
            clr: Colors.red.shade300,
            context: context,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          _bottomSheetButton(
            isClose: true,
            label: 'Close',
            onTap: () {
              Get.back();
            },
            clr: Colors.red.shade300,
            context: context,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

this is delete method.

```
void delete(Task task) {
  DBHelper.delete(task);
  getTask();
  update();
}
```

```
void getTask() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? tasks = await DBHelper.query();
  if (tasks != null) {
    taskList.assignAll(tasks.map((data) => Task.fromJson(data)).toList());
    update();
  } else {
    null;
  }
  print(tasks?.length);
// it is show null when i try to delete the item.
}
```

Comment: Does DBHelper.delete() call setState internally? you possibly need to rebuild the UI after you delete the item from your listview using setState().

Comment: He is using Getx @baek, I think.

Comment: yes, I am using getx

Comment: ui is updating when there is more than one item and when i delete the one of them ui gets rebuild. But the problem is when is there is only one item left and i try to delete it and get deleted but ui does not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh your state after deleting the item, that mean call setState() after deleting the last item